# What should I do? My parents kicked me out of their house because it took my iPad back from them

Tags: parents

I know “my house my rules”but I am 18 and I pay for everything except for food and board. I bought my own vehicles pay the insurance for both of them, and bought my iPad. I work and go to school the latter of which I have had a 4.0 for the last two years. My parents took my iPad because they thought I was spending too much time on it. As an 18 year old I would expect a little more respect than that. Please advise

Comment: Your parents kicked you out? Where do they expect you to go? Do you have friends who you can stay with until this is resolved? What is the resolution you're hoping for? What are you willing to do/give up in order to move back home (if that's your goal?) "Please advise" is too broad a request for this Q&A site. We are here to help, and we really want to help you. Help us with details and a question we can answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

First, on a technical level, view this as an opportunity. It is without a doubt a sink or swim scenario, but it seems you've been swimming for a while anyway, just not really aware of it.

If you're able to clear all those stated responsibility hurdles, clearly with room to spare, I'd say to continue forward and don't look back. You've simply been forced to take the next step, which is all about getting your own place.

To that end, if you are in HS, talk to your counselor at school. They may be able to get you in contact with someone to find some kind of temporary housing, someplace you can stay until you graduate. I've no idea what resources that they may be able to bring to bear, but I believe that is the simplest place to start. Even if you're not a HS student, you could still go back to meet with them once or twice and see what they have to say. If you're in University, a counselor there can fill the same role.

If you're in a major metropolitan area, there may be local organizations you could talk to. A web search would serve you well.

Second, on an emotional/family level, I won't try to pretend to know what could be the root cause of such a negative interaction, but I don't think it matters. As a legal adult, it was pretty much that time anyway.

Further, it's not necessarily "the end" of anything on a family level. It's a transition from "housed kid" to "adult offspring". Assigning blame, trying to figure out why, trying to understand, even trying to be allowed back . . . it's seriously all moot. At some point maybe they'll want to talk to you and try to reconcile the relationship, you know more than anyone how you should respond to that. But what's done is done, and you need to move forward.

As a legal adult, instead of lamenting the change, your only choice here is to take your lumps, accept the challenge, and make the most of it.

I wish you luck.